# Using Blob detection in V-Rep

Tags: simulator, visual-servoing

I was trying to reproduce [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOjQRYmeX_o) youtube tutorial in V-rep and I came across some problems concerning blob detection. There are some complaints on this matter under the video. I don't believe that blob detection stopped working in recent v-rep versions, but I was unable to make it work (as a new v-rep user myself). Has anyone any idea how to properly implement it?

More specifically, I have a vision sensor named `cam` and I want it to follow a red ball. The vision sensor will detect the position of the ball and I will use it to control the joints that steer the sensor (`yaw` and `pitch`). My script follows

```
threadFunction=function()
    yaw=simGetObjectHandle("yaw")
    pitch=simGetObjectHandle("pitch")
    cam=simGetObjectHandle("cam")
    while simGetSimulationState()~=sim_simulation_advancing_abouttostop do
        result,pack1,pack2=simReadVisionSensor(cam)
        if result>0 then
            xtarget=pack2[5]
            ytarget=pack2[6]
            simAuxiliaryConsolePrint(out,string.format("\n x: %0.2f, y: %0.2f",xtarget,ytarget))
            simSetJointTargetVelocity(yaw,1*(0.5-xtarget))
            simSetJointTargetVelocity(pitch,1*(0.5-ytarget))
        end
    end
end

simSetThreadSwitchTiming(2)
out = simAuxiliaryConsoleOpen("Debug",8,1)
res,err=xpcall(threadFunction,function(err) return debug.traceback(err) end)
if not res then
    simAddStatusbarMessage('Lua runtime error: '..err)
end
```

When I run the simulation I can see that the sensor sees the red ball at some point but `result` is always 0 meaning that no detection takes place. [image: image taken during simulation]

Here is [my scene](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hchlzjzabjrmoy/visualServoing.ttt?dl=0)

Comment: "and I came across some problems..." What problems? Your question is extremely vague.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Controller, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see and what you actually saw. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: @MarkBooth
I have modified my question. If it needs any more details please tell me. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I'll move this answer from the comments to an actual answer after this question gets reopened, but until then - I don't know that [this is the correct documentation](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/en/apiFunctions.htm#simReadVisionSensor) for your `simReadVisionSensor` function, but there is a statement on that site that reads, "Reads the state of a vision sensor. **This function doesn't perform detection, it merely reads the result from a previous call to simHandleVisionSensor**.

Comment: It also states later on that it returns, "result: detection state (0 or 1), or **-1 in case of an error, or if simHandleVisionSensor was never called**, or if simResetVisionSensor was previously called." In your code you only ever check if `result > 0`. You never check if there is an error - `result < 0`. Double check that you are initializing the detection correctly (call `simHandleVisionSensor`), and then check if you are truly getting no results (`result == 0`) or if you are getting an error (`result < 0`).

Comment: @Chuck
I have read the documentation. `simHandleVisionSensor` is called in the main script and I think is not supposed to be called again in the child scripts. I am aware of the values `result` can take and I did not check for the other ones because I do not want the sensor to move unless it really detects something. Everything works fine if the ball is initially in the sensor's fov, so I think that there must be something else going on here.

Comment: So you call it when no target is present, then you never call it again? Can you try `if result < 0 then simHandleVisionSensor`? Or `if result == 0 then simHandleVisionSensor`?

Comment: Thanks @Controller, that's great. Interesting question by the way.

Comment: @Chuck
Calling `simHandleVisionSensor` at any time causes an error. I am calling `simReadVisionSensor` inside a while loop that terminates only when terminating the simulation.